# Swimming pool dressing code in Luxembourg

Tags: swimming, luxembourg

this question is related to [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48164/what-swimming-suit-options-are-acceptable-for-a-self-conscious-recreational-swim/48165), nevertheless I'm interested in knowing exactly about Luxembourg. I was quite frustrated about this non-sense rule during the years I lived in Belgium. Swimming life has been quite enjoyable wearing colorful clowny exclusively swimming shorts. Sadly they are not allowed in some countries in Europe (you can notice by my tone how annoyed I feel about it. In fact everytime I think about it I feel like Europe never left the inquisition). I'm planning to be in Luxembourg for one week and I'd like to go to a pool but I don't want to buy a boring tight swimming suit. Plus getting unnecessary things is something to be avoided (general consumerism + global warming stuff).

So, does anyone know whether Luxembourg imposes a tight male dressing code for their pools?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue many swimming pools face is that not only is it becoming difficult to make the difference between actual swimming shorts and shorts you would wear in other circumstances, but many swimming shorts are actually designed to be usable for both (being very quick to dry, mostly).

So many of the younger people will just wear their swimming shorts all day long, and then go to the pool with those rather than bothering to change, which causes all sorts of hygiene and pool maintenance issues.

This (as far as I know) is the main reason many pools in many, many places (not just Europe) will no longer allow swimming shorts but only the skimpy speedo-style swimwear (hoping that people wouldn't go around town wearing those).

However policies are really specific to each pool, so your best bet is to check the rules they publish (usually available on their respective websites).